# how to compare string which contains question mark(?) in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have below code snippet. When comparing using -match command it fails.

```
  $string1 = 'abc?v'
    $string2 = 'abc?v'
    if ($string1 -match $string2)
    {
        Write-Output "Matched"
    }
```

I need to compare weburl in my application and there are chances that weburl can contain **?** in it.

Comment: Check out the `[regex]::Escape()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a literal comparison, you should use the `-eq` comparison operator.  `-match` uses the regex engine to do its comparison where `?` compares the previous token 0 or 1 times, and `-like` from the other answer is a wildcard operator where `[]`, `?` and `*` are interpreted special.

```
if ($string1 -eq $string2) {
```

Answer (score -1):

Use -like instead of -match to get your desired output.

Comment: `-like` and `-match` do two different things; they are not interchangeable. `-match` uses Regular Expressions and doesn't necessarily require wildcards for partial matches; `-like` uses simple wildcards, and must have wildcards for partial matches. The question, as posted, does not really provide enough context to know whether `-like` is a viable alternative - and the question mark is a simple wildcard character, anyway, so even `-like` may have issues.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin In the post, they're looking at urls, so that's a query string they're after.  I posted the correct operator for the job, but I still feel this is an XY problem.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - You're probably right about XY - and probably about using `-eq` as well. I'd want a bit more info from the querent before posting anything I'd consider an answer, though.